# concatenate vectors of an cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation, cell-array

In matlab I have a 4x5 cell array where each cell consists of an 121x1 vector.

What is the easiest way to create an 3-dim 4x5x121 matrix avoiding a 2-fold loop.

Answer (score 7):

One way (not necessarily the fastest)

```
%# convert all arrays in the cell array inCell to 1x1x121
permCell = cellfun(@(x)permute(x,[3,2,1]),inCell,'uniformOutput',false);

%# catenate
array = cell2mat(permCell);
```

Comment: +1, although I believe the first `cellfun` needs a `uniformoutput = false`

Comment: Also needs brackets: `permCell = cellfun(@(x)permute(x,[3,2,1]),inCell,'uniformOutput',false);`

Answer (score 4):

Suppose

```
A = cellfun(@(~)rand(121,1), cell(4,5), 'uniformoutput', false)
```

then normally I would say

```
cat(3, A{:})
```

but that would give a 121-by-1-by-20 array. For your case, an extra step is needed:

```
A = cellfun(@(x)permute(x,3,2,1), A, 'uniformoutput', false)
A = reshape([A{:}], size(A,1), size(A,2), size(A{1},3))
```

or, alternatively,

```
A = cellfun(@(x)permute(x,3,2,1), A, 'uniformoutput', false)
A = cell2mat(A);
```

although

```
>> start = tic;
>> for ii = 1:1e3
>>     B1 = reshape([A{:}], size(A,1), size(A,2), size(A{1},3)); end
>> time1 = toc(start);
>> 
>> start = tic;
>> for ii = 1:1e3
>>     B2 = cell2mat(A); end
>> time2 = toc(start);
>> 
>> time2/time1
ans = 
     4.964318459657702e+00
```

so the command `cell2mat` is almost 5 times slower than the `reshape` of the expansion. Use whichever seems best suited for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The answers by Jonas and Rody are of course fine. A small performance refinement is to `reshape` your vectors in the cells rather than `permute` them:

```
permCell = cellfun(@(x)reshape(x,[1 1 numel(x)]), inCell, 'uni',false);
A = reshape([permCell{:}], [size(inCell) numel(inCell{1,1})]);
```

And by far the fastest, if you can relax the requirements about the output dimensions, is simply concatenating the cell vectors and reshaping

```
A = reshape([inCell{:}], [numel(inCell{1,1}) size(inCell)]);
```

which yields a `[121 x 4 x 5]` matrix.

Comment: Which is **not** faster than `cat(3, A{:})` (well *you* said the requirements on output dimensions could be relaxed :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis oh, ok. I see you refer to your answer. Sorry. I missed that part :) But you also need a reshape then.  `size(cat(3, c{:})) ans = 121  1  20`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, avoiding `cellfun`:

```
 output=permute(cell2mat(permute(input,[3 1 2])),[2 3 1]);
```

Haven't compared speed to the other suggestions though.